# Custom Serialization and Deserialization failing on Stream Test cases

Tags: c#

I'm trying to test my custom serialization and deserializaton logic with memory stream by writing the test cases but unable to test is because of this error while reading the stream during deserializaton.

`EndOfStreamException Unable to read beyond the end of the stream`

Am I using memory stream correctly or should I use some other stream? sharing the code:

```
[TestClass]
public class SerialTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SerializationTestUsingStream()
    {
        Employee emp = new Employee(20);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

        this.SerializeEmployee(stream, emp);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd(); // shows Empty string ""
        var newEmp = this.DeserializeEmployee(stream);
        emp.Should().Equals(newEmp);
    }

    private void SerializeEmployee(Stream stream, Employee collection)
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            writer.Write(collection.age);
        }
    }

    private Employee DeserializeEmployee(Stream stream)
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8, true))
        {
            int age = reader.ReadInt32(); // Exception Comes here while reading from the stream
            return new Employee(age);
        }
    }

    internal class Employee
    {
        public Employee(int age)
        {
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the position of the stream before read it.

```
stream.Position = 0L;
```